# The Great Maid Sweep of 2014 ~ Lets clean up for graduation!

Tags: discussion, cleanup

As was suggested [by Shog9-sama](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/867/49), I hereby call upon all the users to help with some site cleanup, so that we're all tidied up for our big graduation party~

I'd like to ask the community:

- Are there questions we want to get completely rid off?
- Questions left open that should be closed according to new policies set recently?
- Or maybe questions you feel are closed and could be reopened with some editing or because of new rules?
- Are there any good and possibly underrated questions that should be upvoted and/or featured and are there any bad and/or overrated questions buried?

Meta posts such as [this one](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/834/49) have also arrived at some consensus, and its effects should also be rolled in (and [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)'ed as well, for new users).

**Before our big launch we should clean up the house**, so that we won't have a hard time managing once many users lose some of their privileges.
Plus, this is a great time to get a fresh face before a possible swarm of new users (due to our launch), making sure all (or at least most) of our decisions and actions toward posts are consistent (avoiding questions like "Why was mine closed and this one left open?").

Please leave your answer with what you think needs some cleaning up.
Whatever the community decides needs some cleaning up will later be compiled into another meta post with some guidelines and all.

Now unleash the maids!

[image: Ultima Weapon!]

Comment: First order of business - users with delete privileges (I think 2k+ rep?) should examine [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/174544), which lists posts with existing deletion votes, and [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/174559), which lists posts with low scores, evaluate the questions linked from there, and cast deletion votes where available and applicable.

Comment: Another thing to do: check out [the list of questions with 5 or more answers](http://anime.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A5..), and cast upvotes **and** downvotes to ensure that the good answers on these questions float up, while the bad ones sink down. If there are any _egregiously_ bad answers, downvote them (and cast deletion votes if available).

Comment: We should also focus our attention on [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/174662), which lists the questions that have the most views, and which are thus the "face" of our site in a sense, since they draw the most search engine traffic (about 38% of all views are on these 50 questions). As usual, upvote, downvote, edit, flag, delete, post better answers if you have them, etc.

Comment: +1 for "Now unleash the maids!" and the following image

Comment: Yet another thing: we have some users that don't speak English as a first language. This is, of course, totally fine, but it might be nice to go through and edit some of these users' posts for grammar and general readability.

Comment: Add to the check list the tag wiki's/excerpt for attribution.