# Let's cleanup the tag wiki/excerpt!

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki, tag-excerpts, cleanup

As part of the [preparations to the graduation of the site](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/875/2159), I'm proposing to review of all the existent tags wiki/excerpt and write those that aren't still written.

What should you look for:

- It's a dump of an out-site resource? write yourself one.
- Has inaccurateness? Update it.
- Doesn't exist? Write something *original*
- Too short? Expand it.
- Not sure what to do? Ask in [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-)!

For you <strike>lazy like me</strike> efficient users, [I modified some query](http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/revision/175433/224687/tags-with-tag-wikis) in the SEDE to find the ones that are currently written and pasted it below which have more than 10 questions. [This other query will find](http://data.stackexchange.com/anime/revision/175433/224693/tags-without-tag-wikis) the ones that still doesn't exist, so you can find tags to write a master piece!

Comment: I've mentioned this before, but perhaps it's time to standardize formatting of tag wikis for series tags? Not a huge issue but it's a lot easier to do before we graduate since the number of users able to review will drop after graduation.

Comment: @LoganM Sounds like an excellent idea. Thoughts: I'm not sure we need very much content at all in the body of a tag wiki for a series. For very general information like "what is this series about", I think it makes the most sense to just provide a very brief description (~excerpt-sized or so), followed by pointers to places like Wikipedia, MAL, etc for further reading. (With extra information where necessary, of course, e.g. FMA vs. FMAB, disambiguating the Type-Moon universe, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Follows is a list of tags in need of cleanup. Pick your favorite and go go go!

```
Tag                 tag count   tag link
naruto                   372    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/7
identification-request   246    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/188 
anime-production         112    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/17 
one-piece                109    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/1 
fullmetal-alchemist       82    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/35 
tropes                    80    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/113 
bleach                    70    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/28
dragon-ball               44    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/9 
anime-history             43    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/159
pokemon                   40    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/137 
culture                   40    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/147 
japanese-language         33    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/143 
death-note                32    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/14 
fairy-tail                32    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/43 
manga-production          31    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/262 
terminology               25    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/200 
symbolism                 24    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/29 
code-geass                23    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/110 
sword-art-online          23    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/66
monogatari-series         23    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/553 
madoka-magica             22    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/73 
theme-song                20    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/85 
music                     20    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/208 
toaru-majutsu-no-index    20    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/272 
fate-stay-night           18    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/71 
hunter-x-hunter           17    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/103 
neon-genesis-evangelion   16    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/118 
from-the-new-world        16    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/346 
shingeki-no-kyojin        16    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/404 
steins-gate               15    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/25 
manga-history             14    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/308 
nanoha                    14    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/253 
the-world-god-only-knows  13    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/263 
merchandise               13    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/420 
toaru-kagaku-no-railgun   12    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/273 
another                   11    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/510 
mangaka                   11    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/42 
darker-than-black         11    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/115 
cardcaptor-sakura         11    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/91  (needs body)
fate-zero                 11    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/69  (excerpt fixed; needs body)
voice-acting              10    https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/38
```