# What is the purpose of the [mangaka] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

So, as part of the tag wiki cleanup efforts [over here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/881/lets-cleanup-the-tag-wiki-excerpt), I took a look at the [mangaka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mangaka) tag in order to improve it, and then I realized - I have no idea what this tag is supposed to be for! I mean, yes, I know what a "mangaka" is, but that doesn't tell me squat about which questions it's supposed to be used on.

---

Note that 4 of the 11 questions with this tag are also tagged with [manga-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-production). The other questions are:

- [Does Hiro Mashima (Fairy Tail) have something in common with Eiichiro Oda (One Piece)?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/64/does-hiro-mashima-fairy-tail-has-something-in-common-with-eiichiro-oda-one-pi) - about two mangaka, but doesn't need a tag for that.
- [Is there any reliable source that explains the Tsugumi Ohba-Hiroshi Gamo pen name?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/103/is-there-any-reliable-source-that-explains-the-tsugumi-ohba-hiroshi-gamo-pen-nam) - about a mangaka sort of outside the context of the manga, so maybe could benefit from it? But [manga-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-production) would probably still work.
- [How involved was Akira Toriyama in the production of Dragon Ball GT?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/361/was-dragon-ball-gt-made-by-fans) - involves a mangaka, but doesn't need a tag for that.
- [What was Akamatsu Ken's role in creating Negima!? Neo?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/270/what-was-akamatsu-kens-role-in-creating-negima-neo) - well, if we're going to have a [akamatsu-ken](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/akamatsu-ken) tag (which is a strange thing to have), we certainly don't need [mangaka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mangaka) on top of it.
- [Is Dwun (Wdwune) based on Yoshihiro Togashi?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6162/is-dwun-wdwune-based-on-yoshihiro-togashi) - needs a solution similar to the Tsugumi Ohba question
- [What are some of Masamune Shirow's most recent works?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5840/what-are-some-of-masamune-shirows-most-recent-works) - needs a solution similar to the Tsugumi Ohba question.
- https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7233/is-there-a-list-of-banned-manga-artist-whose-work-are-not-translated-into-englis - this question just sucks.

Answer (score 4):

My personal opinion on  [mangaka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mangaka) and [manga-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-production):

- [mangaka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mangaka) needs to be used when the question pertains *directly to a specific mangaka, the job of being a mangaka, or the work a mangaka does*.
- [manga-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-production) by contrast can be *any part of development of manga, including the work a mangaka does*.

So, we have something like a Venn-diagram: some questions may have both tags and be full legitimate, but there will still be questions with just one or the other.

As for specific questions (in order of "newest" in [mangaka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mangaka)):

1. https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7233/is-there-a-list-of-banned-manga-artist-whose-work-are-not-translated-into-englis - VTC'd, I don't know how this wasn't closed sooner. Tags? Probably [mangaka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mangaka)[manga-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-production), but really, who cares? I think the question should be deleted.
2. [Is Dwun (Wdwune) based on Yoshihiro Togashi?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6162/is-dwun-wdwune-based-on-yoshihiro-togashi) - Should remain, and keep [mangaka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mangaka) as it is specific to a mangaka.
3. [What are some of Masamune Shirow's most recent works?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5840/what-are-some-of-masamune-shirows-most-recent-works) - I will not take sides on the validity of this question (as it pertains to lists), but will state that as it pertains directly to a mangaka, should keep [mangaka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mangaka).
4. [Are there any female mangaka pretending to be a male?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3901/are-there-any-female-mangaka-pretending-to-be-a-male) - Pertains directly to the job of being a mangaka (it is highly likely that this question could be answered by an expert on mangaka). Should keep [mangaka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mangaka).
5. [Do manga artists draw their comics by hand or use computers?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3145/do-manga-artists-draw-their-comics-by-hand-or-use-computers) - This one is tough. Definitely [manga-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-production), and I *think* [mangaka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mangaka) would be well-suited here in order to attract appropriate experts.
6. [Is it common for a writer to write for more than one demographic?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3038/is-it-common-for-a-writer-to-write-for-more-than-one-demographic) - Definitely [mangaka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mangaka); doesn't really pertain to production, but to writers specifically.
7. [What is the role of mangaka assistants?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2856/what-is-the-role-of-mangaka-assistants) - Again, tough. Not specifically about mangaka, so I think it should just be [manga-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-production).
8. [How involved was Akira Toriyama in the production of Dragon Ball GT?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/361/was-dragon-ball-gt-made-by-fans) - I think this *just* needs [dragon-ball-gt](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-gt). I don't see this as broadly covered by experts in mangaka (or in anime production).
9. [What was Akamatsu Ken's role in creating Negima!? Neo?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/270/what-was-akamatsu-kens-role-in-creating-negima-neo) - Just [mangaka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mangaka); it's kind of about production, but it's about a *specific* production, so I think it should be kept away from that tag.
10. [Is there any reliable source that explains the Tsugumi Ohba-Hiroshi Gamo pen name?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/103/is-there-any-reliable-source-that-explains-the-tsugumi-ohba-hiroshi-gamo-pen-nam) - Yikes... I think [mangaka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mangaka) is necessary heree, but I'd think we could even remove the other tags.
11. [Does Hiro Mashima (Fairy Tail) have something in common with Eiichiro Oda (One Piece)?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/64/does-hiro-mashima-fairy-tail-has-something-in-common-with-eiichiro-oda-one-pi) - Only peripherally related to mangaka. Should not be tagged with either tag in question.

There we go. I think #1, #7, #8, and #11 can have [mangaka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mangaka) removed, but these definitely need a case-by-case look.

Comment: For the time being, I updated [tag:mangaka] in line with your suggestion. It seems like the tag is doing double duty right now, though - do you think it might make sense to split it off into [tag:specific-mangaka] and [tag:mangaka-profession] or similar?

Comment: @senshin It's hard to say. I'm not sure that's *necessary*, but it does seem like the experts in each category would not be the same. Perhaps bring this up in chat sometime to get some more community input?