# Should answers without explanations be removed?

Tags: discussion

I was reviewing low-quality answers and stumbled over this one: https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/8395/122

Below the answer, there's the following note:

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

"Okay", I thought, "then let's vote to delete it" because it seems like a guess. However, the following reasons for deletion are available:

- No comment needed
- This is an commentary on another post, not an answer
- This is a "Thank You" comment
- This is an "I have a problem, too" comment
- This is a different question posted as an answer
- This is a link-only answer (and not spam)

I don't know what I should choose if the answer has no explanations. Should such answers deleted in the first place?

Comment: Tagged as "support" because I don't think it's a problem with the site and I'm just too stupid.

Answer (score 3):

This has merit for being part of the [clean up](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/875/the-great-maid-sweep-of-2014-lets-clean-up-for-graduation). If you see such a question or comment be sure to flag it for us to review (answers and comments). We'll check to see if our meidos need to take care of it!

Comment: Is this not an ongoing issue though?

Comment: not really it doesn't really happen too frequently, but it doesn't hurt to keep track of it so it doesn't get out of hand.

Comment: Also doesn't hurt (well, okay, it hurts a bit) to just downvote it. Once it hits -3 it doesn't really distract from the post anymore.